# var not getting value and I dont know why

Tags: node.js

I am trying to assign a value from an input box to a var but when I pass it to the function its just blank object?

```
var newUser = {'username': $('#findUser fieldset input#inputSearchUser').val()}

populateTableFind(newUser);
```

but the result is blank?

If I do:

```
populateTableFind($('#findUser fieldset input#inputSearchUser').val());
```

then it works... I don't know why? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here, thanks.

Comment: You are calling `populateTableFind` with two different values, one is object and another string.

Comment: how can I make it right? sorry I am new to Jscript

Comment: you are creating an object with a key and value, you should pass the value by its key. populateTableFind(newUser.username);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case try

```
var newUser =  $('#findUser fieldset input#inputSearchUser').val();
```

You should get the same result.

Comment: What does the $ mean?

Comment: this looks like a jQuery symbol. Is this question about `node.js` or `javascript`

Comment: it is about node.js

Comment: then I am confused, best disregard my answer